# Use of Unassigned Variable

Tags: c#

I am getting the error `"use of unassigned variable ch" at while (ch != 'n')`

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char ch;

    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter any number");

        int i = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int j = 1; j <= 200; j++)
        {
            int c = i * j;
            Console.Write("  " + c);

            if (j % 10 == 0)
                Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("again? " + "(y//n)");
        ch = Convert.ToChar(Console.ReadLine());

        if (ch == 'y' || ch == 'n') 
            continue;
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("invalid choice");
            break;
        }
    } while (ch != 'n');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried initializing ch?? before allowing it to enter the loop?

Comment: Basically, the compiler is following the rules of the language - which means it doesn't "know" that you always enter the body of the `for` loop.

Comment: Yeah..  initialize it, just to shut the compiler up :)

Comment: thanks Rahul Jha.I think initializing is not necessary in c++ that's why i neglect it

Comment: @JonSkeet the compiler is following the rules of C#, and that too in depth. :)

Comment: *.I think initializing is not necessary in c++* , well, yes and no, it's not enforced but it's usually necessary, in c++ that variable would have a random value (the previous value allocated on the memory address) and that would yield unexpected results. Exactly for that C# compiler enforces the variable initialization.

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly what it says. `ch` is uninitialized before it's value is used, resulting in an error.

Something simple, like `ch = 'Z'` or `ch = ' '` will fix the problem.

Answer (score -2):

You have not initialized the char variable 'ch' before entering the loop. You can initialize it before hand.

```
char ch='y';
```

Fix it, and it will just shut the compiler's mouth up.
Edit: Any value to ch will work except 'n' due to while condition.

Comment: Did you test that to see if it works? You're assigning a `char` a `string`. That doesn't throw an error? That's like saying `int num = new int[]`.

Comment: Edited. The double "" was just the mistake, and yes, that can't be empty.

Comment: I would use something like `'\n'` or `' '` to use as a blank `char`.